# Include inside function (CURL)

Tags: php

My settings file with the url is config.php, config.php contains yoursite.com

I want to use curl_init() function, like

curl_init(include config.php/file.php); something like that, is that possible?

Comment: One could use [`curl_setopt_array`](http://php.net/curl_setopt_array) after initializing, with the config file returning a config array. Or make a wrapper function etc.

Comment: @alexandru  
you can use `include config.php` or `require confg.php` and you can pass the variable to `curl_init($url)` where `$url` is a variable in your `config.php` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's illegal syntax. What are you trying to have it do?

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you have a configuration file with the URL of the website.
If you follow the conventions of config files in PHP. The config file will look like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'website' => 'http://www.example.com'
];
```

The best thing would be to include the configuration file at the top of your file. First

```
$config = include_once("config");
```

The config file would be an array of configuration values.

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['website']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// And you see the content of the website
var_dump($response);
```

You could improve this be working with namespaces.

The following link has most of the information about it.

http://php.net/language.namespaces

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your problem.

The CURL PHP basically works in this manner:

```
<?php
$url = 'yoursite.com';
$channel  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($channel);
curl_close($channel);

//you can dump the response here
var_dump($response);
```

You can include your configurations in another file, but is more easy if you create a class to abstract this functionality